# load external modal javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have main HTML file and JavaScript file I have used modal in my project on button click the modal from another file would be shown, I have used the code but it's not working.

On button click in function search() the modal should be shown and the modal.HTML content is based according to the id passed

I am getting errors are

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:6)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Here is the code

index.html

```
<body>
   <!--some code-->
   <div id="mymodal"> </div>
</body>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.Links').on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#mymodal').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load("next.html?id="+id);
    });
$("#submit").click(function() {
    Search(search);
});
});

function Search(search) {
    '<button class="button Links" data-toggle="modal" id='+id+'>See Details</button>'
}
```

next.html

```
<div id="mymodal2" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Model Box</h4>
        </div>
<div class="modal-body">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Update:

I was having error because of not including the files properly. Now i have solved them but problem is half solved. Now when button clicked the screen became dull like when modal is shown and background became dull but in my case no modal is shown

Comment: Your selectors aren't correct for delegating event on `.Links` class. There is no `[data-toggle="modal"]` **inside** `.Links` it is on same element. Also appears you may be adding more `'.Links` so you need to delegate higher up the dom tree to an ancestor that always exists

Comment: See: *[Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)*

Comment: @charlietfl can you help me with suggesting the correct way to do it?

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click', '.Links[data-toggle="modal"]', function() {..`

Comment: still not working

Comment: That isn't very informative. Is click working? does modal open? does request get made in dev tools network?

Comment: on button click nothing is happening.

Comment: any errors in console? Have you tried logging anything into console inside click handler?

Comment: errors updated in question please check

Comment: so it seems you didn't include bootstrap.js, or path is wrong or you include jQuery.js more than once in page

Comment: hey i have solved the errors. i have not included the bootstrap files properly. Now when the button is clicked the screen became dull like when the modal is shown but nothing is showing on the screen only dull screen